# using regex to select value in python

Tags: python, regex

I want regex to select 00:01:00, however, it takes 07:59:00. So decided to search not only based on date format, but to look for " in front of date format as well.

```
lineItems = ["2022-08-15T07:59:00,row1,"00:01:00","2022-08-15T08:00:00"]
```

`lineItems` is a list. I have to pick the format that is similar to 00:01:00

The script I use is below:

```
matches = re.search('(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', str(lineItems))
```

Could you please assist to edit the script, so it looks for `"` in front of datetime, but grab only DateTime without `"`.

Thanks

Comment: If you need just 00:01:00 then '00:01:00' can help you out

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have to get DateTime as a string. lineItems is list itself. I just wrote it as string in question in order not to add all row

Comment: The " is not really there, it just shows up when printing to tell you it's a string

Comment: I iterate throw several lines, and this one I have mentioned as an example. Format of all lines will be the same.

Comment: Maybe you need https://ideone.com/YB5ZA4?

Comment: You can try https://regex101.com/

Comment: There is no way Python scripts doesn't raise errors on `lineItems = "2022-08-15T07:59:00,row1,"00:01:00","2022-08-15T08:00:00"`

Comment: Thanks everyone for assistance. Did not write string in a correct way, sorry for that. In real case, lineItems is a list. I have follow Wiktor's code and it worked.

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73746256/3832970) with a more Python-specific solution, note the `re.fullmatch` does not require the pattern to contain anchors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
 
lineItems = ["2022-08-15T07:59:00","row1","00:01:00","2022-08-15T08:00:00"]
r = re.compile(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
print( list(filter(r.fullmatch, lineItems)) )
# => ['00:01:00']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YB5ZA4).

Note that `r.fullmatch` requires a full string match, so there is no need adding anchors to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookbehind to make sure it's preceded by `"`.

```
matches = re.search('(?<=")(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', str(lineItems))
```

Comment: For some reason it did not work in my case.                                                                            I have written a bit-long script,:
                r = re.compile(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})')
                matches = filter(r.fullmatch, lineItems)
                matches = list(matches)
                time = str(matches[0])
                # matches = str(list(matches))
                duration = time.split(":")
                hours= float(duration[0]) + float(float(duration[1])/60)
                hours = f"{hours:,.2f}"
                lineItems[4] =hours